# can't access prestashop login admin still get tis error message ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: .htaccess, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Since two days I can't access prestashop login admin, I still get this error message:

> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

I've already:

- checked `PS_SHOP_DOMAIN` and `PS_SHOP_DOMAIN_SSL` in `ps_configuration` table
- Delete the `.htaccess` at the root of the application folder.

But I'm still getting this error message:

> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

**Note:** That the front office is well display.

Comment: So... what changed two days ago?

Comment: can you share your admin/ftp details on my email ravinder2432@gmail.com?

Comment: Check network tab and see which links are opening and figure out the issue.

Comment: @user82217 nothing have changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution. It was that my admin has been hacked (hacked by bajatax).
They uploaded through one of these the scripts `/modules/up.php`, `/modules/fieldvmegamenu/uploads/hous.php` and remove `AdminLoginController.php`. The failing module was `/modules/fieldvmegamenu`

I deleted all suspicious files, and disabled the module

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

There must be some error in your log file. Check the error from log file and resolve the issue